# Drag and drop issues on IE9 and IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

I am currently trying to implement a drag and drop feature on my project. It seems to work fine on Chrome, Firefox and even IE11, but not IE9 and IE10 (which need to be supported).

It seems that these two browsers doesn't update `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` when moving the mouse while dragging an object: it keeps the original click coordinates. Here is the code I am using:

```js
$("html").on("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("html").on("dragenter", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("html").on("dragleave", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("html").on("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    
    updateXY(event);
});

function updateXY(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var originalEvent = e.originalEvent;
    var x = originalEvent.clientX;
    var y = originalEvent.clientY;
    
    $("#draggable").css({ top: y, left: x });
    $("#x").text(x);
    $("#y").text(y);
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#draggable {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    cursor: move;
}

#droppable {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div droppable="true" id="droppable">
    <div draggable="true" id="draggable">Hello world!</div>
</div>
<p>Coordinates: <span id="x">10</span> ; <span id="y">10</span></p>
```

And a JSFiddle is also available: http://jsfiddle.net/tq2zvg41/4/

How can I do?

Comment: As a side note: I know drop is not perfect as it takes upper left corner as position, but it is to simplify this snippet. :)

Comment: Have you tried screenX ?

Comment: Same behavior: it is not updated.

Comment: [`draggable/droppable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) properties are not supported in IE9. Your fiddle seems to work in IE10 (emulated with IE11 though) and 11 and Chrome, but for some reason it doesn't drag and drop in FF...

Comment: Any solution found anyone? ?